# Filereader возвращает строку которую нельзя корректно декодировать

Tags: javascript, python

Добрый день.
Есть код получения base64 для передачи через json файла(картинка/архив).

```
function getBase64(file, callback) {
        var result = '';
        var file_name = '';
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function () {
        console.log("return file in base64: " + reader.result);
            var encoded_file = reader.result;
            console.log('return base64...');
            callback(file.name,encoded_file);
        };
        reader.onerror = function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
            return callback(file_name,'');
        };
}
```

если данную строку декодировать в python

```
attachment = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
attachment.set_payload(base64.b64decode(file['file64']))
email.encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename="%s"' % file['filename'])
msg.attach(attachment)
```

То файл нечитаемый получается. Может я что-то делаю не так? По другому кодировать файл нужно и декодировать его обратно? (btoa пробовал).

UPD1:
Ок, давайте переформатируем вопрос.
Есть строка получаемая от формы через JSON вида:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJR------TUT-ESCHO-BASE64-CODE------AAAAAAAAAAB/9k=
```

Как её правильно декодировать в файл? или добавить в аттач письма?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь data URI прочитать? `data = urllib.request.urlopen('data:...').read()`

Comment: попробовал urlopen - увы, попрежнему не читаемый вывод

Comment: urllib успешно работает с data URI. К примеру, `urlretrieve("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==", "image.png")`

Comment: Да, urlretrieve именно оно. Пришлось правда tmpfile подключать, так как не хотело работать с (file, header) = retrieve(), Но это уже мелочи. Спасибо.

Comment: urlretrieve это обёртка для удобства вокруг urlopen. Это значит, что urlopen работает в вашем случае. Упрощённо: `urlretrieve = lambda url, path: copyfileobj(urlopen(url), open(path,'wb'))`

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо jfs за подсказку. Для декодирования необходим urlretreive.
Код js:

```
function getBase64(file, callback) {
        var result = '';
        var file_name = '';
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function () {
            var encoded_file = reader.result;
            callback(file.name,encoded_file);
        };
        reader.onerror = function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
            return callback(file_name,'');
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Собственно код преткновения на **python**  выглядит так:

```
attachment = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+b', delete=False)
filename = str(f.name)

urllib.urlretrieve(file['file64'], filename)
f.close

FILE = open(filename)
attachment.set_payload(FILE.read())

email.encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
filename_header = file['filename'].encode('utf-8')
attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment', filename=('utf-8', 'ru', filename_header))


msg.attach(attachment)
FILE.close
os.remove(FILE.name)
```

Можно обойтись без временных файлов, но у меня (filename, header) = urlretrieve() возвращал такое значение, что *FILE* воспринимал его как dict и отказывался открывать даже после приведения к строке через str()

Comment: Вам не нужен urlretrieve. Вместо `FILE.read()` подставьте: `urlopen(file['file64']).read()`. MIMEBase отвлекает от сути вопроса (получению данных из data URI). Хотя не ясно, что мешает послать байты как есть в javascript, не кодируя их в data URI. Тогда на стороне Питона, `FILE.read()` это просто  `file["file64"]`.

Comment: urlopen(file['file64']).read(). - Этот вариант я пробовал одним из первых и он не зашёл - файл создавался, но не отображался. data URI используется потому, что файл передаётся при помощи  JSON, а не get/post запросом

Comment: чудес не бывает. Если `urlretrieve()` у вас работает, то и `urlopen().read()` обязан работать.

Comment: Значит я что-то делал не так, но в таком варианте у меня "завелось",ч ему я несказанно рад, хотя решение и корявое.